# Pergunta erroneamente marcada como duplicada

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

A pergunta [Personagem do Nightmares não se move](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76319/personagem-do-nightmares-n%C3%A3o-se-move) foi erroneamente marcada como duplicada (da pergunta [Nightmares - Personagem não se movimenta, parado na animação Idle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75568/nightmares-personagem-n%C3%A3o-se-movimenta-parado-na-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-idle#comment156876_75568)), muito provavelmente porque quem votou para tal o fez apenas baseado no título e no fato de que ambas seguem o mesmo tutorial (do @Nils). É um erro honesto, mas basta ler as respostas existentes nas questões pra perceber que não se trata do mesmo problema.

Independentemente da qualidade das questões (que vou mencionar novamente logo a seguir), eu acho importante lembrar que nós (como comunidade) precisamos tomar cuidado ao escolher as razões do voto pra fechar perguntas, principalmente se não entendemos muito do assunto (não estou dizendo que foi necessariamente o caso de todos que votaram). Essa razão é importante para não somente evitar de desmotivar os APs, como também para não iludir nenhum outro usuário que procura respostas para problemas similares.

Sobre a qualidade de ambas essas questões, eu admito que elas não são questões muito boas. Se fosse votar para fechá-las (a ambas!), eu votaria para fazê-lo como **fora do escopo**. Ambas as questões são muito específicas, praticamente decorrentes de erros de digitação/execução (a segunda, principalmente). Mas, considerando a baixa qualidade geral das perguntas na tag [unity-3d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-3d) até o momento, eu optei por não fazê-lo porque estou (junto com tantos outros colegas, principalmente o @Nils) tentando estimular os usuários dessa tecnologia na comunidade a aprenderem a usar o SOPT e tentando ajudar a melhorar a qualidade desse conteúdo.

Enfim, se julgarem necessário fechar alguma pergunta (ou ambas), eu proponho que isso seja feito ao menos com o motivo apropriado. Será que os moderadores conseguem alterar o motivo do fechamento em uma pergunta já fechada?

> EDIÇÃO: Esta outra pergunta
>   ([Animaçao nao carrega -Nightmares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76604/anima%C3%A7ao-nao-carrega-nightmares)),
>   do mesmo AP da pergunta linkada acima, já está sendo fechada como
>   duplicada novamente. Eu não sei qual é a pergunta que está sendo apontada como
>   duplicada, pois eu já havia votado para fechá-la como ampla
>   anteriormente (até o autor melhorar a pergunta). Esta, em especial, eu
>   não acho que deveria ser fechada. O @Nils já deu uma ótima resposta em
>   seus dois últimos comentários (só faltaria converter em resposta
>   mesmo), e isso não é algo específico - tem muito potencial para ajudar
>   outros usuários futuros.

Comment: Acho que um moderador pode abrir e fechar de novo com o motivo certo. Mas se é caso de deixar aberto pelas razões de incentivo para a comunidade da [tag:unity-3d] podiamos deixar aberta.

Comment: @Sergio Eu não sei se é o caso de deixar aberta. Eu só justifiquei o meu não-voto para fechar *naquele momento* (da postagem das questões). Acho que como os APs já tiveram seus problemas satifeitos e o incentivo para que eles melhorassem o conteúdo também foi feito (nos comentários), as respostas poderiam ser corretamente fechadas. Até porque o seu fechamento não impede que esse conteúdo seja acessado no futuro por outros usuários, certo? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira eu fui um dos que votou para fechar, e sinceramente não me lembro do motivo que coloquei, mas lembro-me que pensei nesse motivo que enuncias. Já tivemos essa discussão algures se o motivo certo é o importante ou se o importante é que a pergunta esteja fechada.

Comment: [Motivo de fechamento de uma pergunta errado, o que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1957/motivo-de-fechamento-de-uma-pergunta-errado-o-que-fazer)

Comment: O primeiro principalmente tem que acertar porque os outros quatro que votarão a seguir provavelmente confirmação sem ler a pergunta :P

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu acho que perdi essa discussão, mas obrigado por mencioná-la. Li lá, e concordo que uma organização é importante. Mas não pensei se a organização atual está boa ou não. Só achei que nesse caso o motivo de fechamento não está correto. Fechar uma pergunta tem a principal motivação de evitar que ela continua recebendo respostas, uma vez que ela não está de acordo com as regras aqui propostas. Certo? Então, eu acho importante fechar assim que possível. Mas isso *não quer dizer* que a indicação do motivo adequado não é importante.

Comment: @JorgeB. Afinal, sem o motivo correto, como o AP (mesmo que experiente) vai saber onde errou e como corrigir o problema, para que sua pergunta atual (e as perguntas novas no futuro) se encaixe nas regras propostas?

Comment: @LuizVieira eu concordo, acho que o motivo é importante. Mas se toda a gente vota com o motivo errado eu voto com o certo que se há de fazer? Só se sinalizar a um moderador...

Comment: @JorgeB. Bom, o jeito é sinalizar a um moderador nesses casos. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira eu nesse caso nem me recordo se votei no motivo certo, mas tenho a certeza que dei voto a pensar no motivo certo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não se preocupe. A minha colocação não tem a intenção de apontar o dedo a ninguém. Eu só queria "lembrar" a comunidade de que o motivo do fechamento é importante (e se você se importa com isso também, ótimo!) e ao mesmo tempo pedir aos moderadores que mudassem o motivo do fechamento (se eles concordarem, claro).

Comment: @LuizVieira eu bem sei que não, estou me a justificar porque não me lembro se fiz o certo ou se fiz errado. Mas que foi ponderado, isso foi.

Comment: @LuizVieira mas se os moderadores mudarem isso não estão a ir contra a ideia de quem fechou? Não sei se será a melhor política. Até agora só um dos votantes se manifestou, eu.

Comment: @JorgeB. Verdade. Podemos votar pra reabrir e depois votar pra fechar novamente com o que julgarmos mais correto?

Comment: @LuizVieira também não sei se isso é boa ideia. Porque a resposta estará reaberta durante algum tempo e podem surgir respostas. Deixa ver se algum moderador diz alguma coisa ou responde a isto.

Comment: @Sergio Viu essas últimas linhas de discussão? O que você acha?

Comment: Concordo com o @JorgeB. Eu particularmente penso assim, o que pode ser fechado também pode ser reaberto, é melhor fechar algo para evitar respostas em hora indevida, no rodapé existe uma explicação do motivo do fechamento, se o usuário não tolera este tipo de sistema então este site não é pra ele. Existe o meta pra discutir e você pode convida-lo a participar da discussão pra ele não se sentir tão injustiçado, acho que fui eu quem votou também pra fechar. Pra mim o correto era quem respondeu ter melhorado a pergunta pra não se confundir com outras.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu coloquei o link para esta discussão lá nas três perguntas que são aqui mencionadas. Eu entendo e concordo com a ideia de fechar rápido. Mas, mesmo assim, acho que um certo cuidado é devido. O AP provavelmente não tem experiência suficiente pra reclamar, e se eu não tivesse feito a pergunta talvez permanecesse fechada com o motivo errado. Pior do que isso, se eu não tivesse respondido antes dela ser fechada, o motivo levaria qualquer outro usuário (provavelmente tão inexperiente quanto o AP) a crer que a solução do problema está lá na outra pergunta, o que não é verdade.

Comment: Luiz talvez eu não tenha me expressado direito, eu concordo com o cuidado, apenas o que eu quero dizer é que algo que é fechado pode ser reaberto e assim como usuários novos podem errar, os veteranos também podem. Não há mal algum em faze-lo, desde que possa ser revertido.

Comment: Eu reabri a pergunta, mas também estou em dúvida sobre fechar novamente. A outra, que era o destino da duplicata, eu fechei como fora de escopo (erro de digitação).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ah, ok. Desculpe também, talvez eu tenha entendido errado a sua colocação. :) Enfim, é isso mesmo. Como eu disse, erros honestos acontecem.

Comment: @LuizVieira desculpa responder só agora, o trabalho não me deixou vir aqui mais cedo. Mas pelo que percebo o bfavaretto já deu o passo para acertar o problema.

Comment: @Sergio Não se preocupe. Mesmo assim, obrigado. :)

Comment: Meus três centavos baseados nas últimas perguntas que respondi sobre Unity:
- Desenvolvendo jogos, com engine ou não, dizer meu personagem não anda(bem comum aqui) podem ser diversas coisas desde código, até falta de memória no dispositivo. Então, independente do tempo de casa do AP, veremos muitas perguntas com títulos iguais, descrições semelhantes e códigos idênticos. Neste caso, eu sugiro ponderar bem antes de marcar/suspender. Vi "mesma pergunta" com erro de maiúscula no código, e num outro momento uma comparação errada por outra pessoa.Quando consigo responder antes de bloquearem, aviso.

Comment: - Existem muitas pessoas se interessando por desenvolvimento a partir de jogos, eu escolhi minha educação desde pequeno por causa deste motivo. Mas independente de idade veremos muitas perguntas bizarras em letras maiúsculas ou em `mIgUXêZz`, pessoas desesperadas achando que é o fim do mundo, até dizendo que tentaram coisas absurdas para fazer funcionar e nada sobre o problema/detalhes. Neste caso pode lacrar sem pensar duas vezes, sendo jogo ou não, não tem como ajudar algumas loucuras que aparecem. O importante é tentar orientar o AP a melhorar a questão, como já vejo muitos aqui fazerem.

Comment: - O que vai para a último centavo, essa "lacrada" serve como filtro de interesse da resposta, alguns autores aproveitam os comentários para melhorar a pergunta (suspensa ou não) e pedem para abrir, alguns já foram chorar para mim e consegui orientar eles, as vezes eu mesmo edito a pergunta quando consigo traduzir o "hieroglifo" na primeira lida. Mas tem outros que postam a pergunta e abandonam ela, se o cara não tem interesse em manter ela aberta, talvez não precise da nossa ajuda tanto assim.

Comment: Acho que os dois últimos estão bem adequados as regras daqui, oficiais e implícitas. Sendo um cuidado diferente só na análise da pergunta. Mas me surpreendo que não tiveram problemas semelhantes com base de dados ou BI. Também existem questões que vão além da query SLQ. Pensando melhor, diversas áreas de conhecimento podem ter problemas que vão além da descrição.